# Oracle apex list manager for multiple choices

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have a question about list manager. I have list manager that allows the student to choose the courses that he want to register the scenario as follow: when the student select the courses then click button called “register” the courses he chosen fetched into another table called “Stu_Courses” to store the ID Of the student with the courses that he selected . Anyone idea of how can I did this scenario.

Thank you
[example of my list manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82KSX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When your page is submitted, in page processing you just need to insert the values into the table.

#### Example Query

```
SELECT 123 AS student_id, COLUMN_VALUE AS course_id FROM TABLE (apex_string.split ('1:2:3', ':'));
```

#### Example with APEX Items

```
INSERT INTO stu_courses
    SELECT :P2_STUDENT_ID AS student_id, COLUMN_VALUE AS course_id
      FROM TABLE (apex_string.split ( :P2_SELECTED_COURSES, ':'));
```